# Simplifying jQuery events

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, simplify

I wrote these functions to handle data when a particular cell of my table is clicked. I have 6 functions that handle the data for the event but each are the same, they just with a different ID. Here is my code:

```
    //COMMENT HANDLING
    $("#mondayCommentLink").click(function () {
        var mondayhtmls = $("#mondayComment");
        var input = $("<input type='text' id='mondayCommentText' name='mondayCommentText' size='10' />");
        input.val(data.days[0].comment);
        mondayhtmls.html(input);
    });

    $("#tuesdayCommentLink").click(function () {
        var tuesdayhtmls = $("#tuesdayComment");
        var inputt = $("<input type='text' id='tuesdayCommentText' name='tuesdayCommentText' size='10' />");
        inputt.val(data.days[1].comment);
        tuesdayhtmls.html(inputt);
    });

    $("#wednesdayCommentLink").click(function () {
        var htmls = $("#wednesdayComment");
        var input = $("<input type='text' id='wednesdayCommentText' name='wednesdayCommentText' size='10' />");
        input.val(data.days[2].comment);
        htmls.html(input);
    });

    $("#thursdayCommentLink").click(function () {
        var htmls = $("#thursdayComment");
        var input = $("<input type='text' id='thursdayCommentText' name='thursdayCommentText' size='10' />");
        input.val(data.days[3].comment);
        htmls.html(input);
    });

    $("#fridayCommentLink").click(function () {
        var htmls = $("#fridayComment");
        var input = $("<input type='text' id='fridayCommentText' name='fridayCommentText' size='10' />");
        input.val(data.days[4].comment);
        htmls.html(input);
    });

    $("#saturdayCommentLink").click(function () {
        var htmls = $("#saturdayComment");
        var input = $("<input type='text' id='saturdayCommentText' name='saturdayCommentText' size='10' />");
        input.val(data.days[5].comment);
        htmls.html(input);
    });
```

Is there a way I can simply this code or make it more elegant than having 6 separate functions handling each specific cell event?

Comment: This is sort of a code review, which would go on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var dayNums = {"monday": 0, "tuesday": 1, "wednesday": 2, "thursday": 3, "friday": 4, "saturday": 5};
$("#mondayCommentLink, #tuesdayCommentLink, #wednesdayCommentLink, #thursdayCommentLink, #fridayCommentLink, #saturdayCommentLink").click(function () {
    var day = $(this).attr("id").replace(/CommentLink$/, "");
    var htmls = $("#" + day + "Comment");
    var input = $("<input type='text' id='" + day + "CommentText' name='" + day + "CommentText' size='10' />");
    input.val(data.days[dayNums[day]].comment);
    htmls.html(input);
});
```

Comment: I consider it not dry at all.

Answer (score 2):

If each of the links have a common class (or you can give them one), then you can use it as the selector. Additionally, add something like `data-day="1"` to the tag, with the number corresponding to the position (0 for monday, 1 for tuesday...).

Then, start your function with:

```
var day = this.id.match(/(\w+)CommentLink/)[1],
    comment = data.dats[this.getAttribute("data-day")].comment;
```

Then you can do things like `$("#"+day+"Comment")`, `id='"+day+"CommentText'` and so on.

Comment: Would also need a convertor to get the index to `days[..]` - but yes.

Comment: I would normally use `replace` for this. Which would be more efficient? `var day = this.id.replace('CommentLink', '');`

Comment: @Orbling Erm, no, because `days` will be the string name.

Comment: @dKen Either works, but mine will throw an error if the ID doesn't match, for whatever reason, instead of just assuming it's okay and carrying on.

Comment: @Kolink: It's not in his code... eg. `input.val(data.days[3].comment);`

Comment: `data.days` is not the same as a local variable `days`.

Comment: Ah, right, I see what you mean. Yes, that could be a problem, to be fixed with an attribute.

Answer (score 2):

Add the attribute data-dow="2" and data-day="wednesday" to each comment link, remove the id="wednesdayCommentLink" and add class="commentLink".

```
<a class="wednesdayCommentLink">link</a>
```

becomes

```
<a class="commentLink" data-dow="2" data-day="wednesday">link</a>
```

Do the same for #wednesdayComment (.comment) and #wednesdayCommentText (.commentText), adding the data- attributes for each.

Then, use this JavaScript:

```
$(".commentLink").click(function () {
    var dow = $(this).attr('data-dow');
    var day = $(this).attr('data-day');

    var input = $('<input type="text" class="commentText" data-dow="'+dow+'" data-day="'+day+'" name="'+day+'CommentText" size="10" />');
    input.val(data.days[dow].comment);

    $('.comment[data-dow="'+dow+'"]').html(input);
});
```

Comment: There's no reason to store `data-dow` **and** `data-day` - you could easily use a lookup instead of duplicating a lot

Comment: @prothid Awesome... we had the exact same answer, independently... must be the way to go

Comment: @Ian Sure, though technically he asked how to simplify the jQuery event, not his html. =)

Comment: @KirkB. Though this one uses the `data-...` attributes rather than custom, which could be considered more robust, particularly pre-HTML5.

Comment: @prothid I don't understand. If anything, you're **complicating** things by duplicating and adding stuff. It's not that big of a deal, I was just saying, because the `dow` and `day` should always match up

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there's lot that can be done. But when refactoring I recommend starting out small. So first just move the common code of the event handler into a seperate function:

```
var handler = function(day,commentId,commentTextId) {
  return function () {
    var input = $("<input type='text' id='"+commentTextId+"' name='"+commentTextId+"' size='10' />");
    input.val(day.comment);
    $('#'+commentId).html(input);
  };
};
```

Then you can setup your events like so:

```
$("#mondayCommentLink").click(handler(data.days[0],"mondayComment","mondayCommentText"));
$("#tuesdayCommentLink").click(handler(data.days[1],"tuesdayComment","tuesdayCommentText"));
// and so on
```

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is to create a class for the commentLinks so you are able to write only once the click event for each element, and I wouldn't remove the id to do something like:

```
jQuery('.commentLink').click(function(){
  var elementId = jQuery(this).attr('id');
  var sectionName = elementId.substring(0, elementId.lastIndexOf('Link'));
  var htmls = jQuery('#' + sectionName);
  var input = jQuery("<input type='text' id='" + sectionName + "Text' name='" + sectionName + "Text' size='10' />");
  htmls.html(input);
});
```

And that's all.